# spark ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query terminated with error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to send streaming data to the Kafka using the Spark streaming method.But the spark job is not initiating the task and its failing by given the error message as "MicroBatchExecution: Query terminated with error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext".

I submit the application as follows:

```
/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/bin/spark-submit \
  --class com.test.testone.kafkaStream.KafkaProducer \
  --master yarn \
  --deploy-mode client \
  --executor-memory 2G \
  --num-executors 4 \
  --jars /home/yeswanth/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.0.jar,/home/yeswanth/jars/kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar \
  /home/yeswanth/jars/kafkaStreams-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Please find the code below.

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName("Spark-Kafka-Integration")
  .master("local[1]")
  .getOrCreate()


val mySchema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("id", IntegerType),
  StructField("name", StringType),
  StructField("year", IntegerType),
  StructField("rating", DoubleType),
  StructField("duration", IntegerType)
))

val streamingDataFrame = spark.readStream.schema(mySchema).csv("Path")


streamingDataFrame.selectExpr("CAST(id AS STRING) AS key", "to_json(struct(*)) AS value")
  .writeStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("topic", "topicname")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "alpha:6667")
  .option("checkpointLocation","path")
  .outputMode("append")
  .start()
```

The stack trace is given below:

````
19/10/14 02:11:19 INFO FileStreamSource: maxFilesPerBatch = None, maxFileAgeMs = 604800000
19/10/14 02:11:19 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = c6d99dc8-6dfd-4088-b1fa-7558c7ec8305, runId = 418bd5a2-c9fe-4d6c-8027-997a6a11e298] terminated with error
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.
This stopped SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:921)
com.test.testone.kafkaStream.KafkaProducer$.main(KafkaProducer.scala:18)
com.test.testone.kafkaStream.KafkaProducer.main(KafkaProducer.scala)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:906)
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)


The currently active SparkContext was created at:

org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:921)
com.test.testone.kafkaStream.KafkaProducer$.main(KafkaProducer.scala:18)
com.test.testone.kafkaStream.KafkaProducer.main(KafkaProducer.scala)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:906)
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.assertNotStopped(SparkContext.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.<init>(SparkSession.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.cloneSession(SparkSession.scala:252)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:268)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:189)
19/10/14 02:11:19 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
19/10/14 02:11:19 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
19/10/14 02:11:19 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
19/10/14 02:11:19 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
19/10/14 02:11:19 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
19/10/14 02:11:19 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
19/10/14 02:11:19 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
19/10/14 02:11:19 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-8a0488a0-77e0-43ee-a5d3-d50847a9531d
19/10/14 02:11:19 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-2e344c85-4324-4563-93fa-f5a9392873bb```
````

Comment: Do you use `--master yarn` on command-line and hardcoded the `.master("local[1]")`?! Please remove the `.master("local[1]")` line from the Spark app and start over.

Comment: removed the .master("local[1]") from code and re executed the code.But still getting the same error as the stack trace

Comment: There's something going on earlier. Don't you have any other errors or exceptions earlier? What's at the line `KafkaProducer.scala:18`? Do you have any other code before? Can you show the entire object (the Spark app)? Just to let what you showed execute.

Comment: Could you remove `--jars` from spark-submit and use `--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.0` instead?